# Is there anyway to remove denied permissions from a group for a folder if I dont have access?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, security, group-policy

I'm hoping the answer is yes.

Due to my ignorance, I denied the 'Everyone' group all read access from one of my folders containing needed information because I did not want people on my network being able to view my data.  I didn't realize that I could not remove myself from the everyone group, and therefore I can no longer view the data/files in the folder.

I can view all other information on the c:\ drive and such, just not this folder.  Is there anyway to remove the denied rights from the 'Everyone' group on this folder?  My account is an administrator, however from the GUI it will not let me edit security information on the folder when I right-click it and go to the security tab.

Windows OS : Vista

Comment: Which permissions specifically did you deny? Only the read data / read attributes / read extended attributes? or did you just click deny full control?

Comment: The only permissions that were allowed for 'Everyone' on my folder were 'Read & Execute', 'List folder Contents', and 'Read'.  I denied those three.

Comment: Then you should be able to skip the `takeown` step of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, don't mess with the permissions unless you know what you are doing. At the very least, you should read the Technet article on "ACL permissions" and "How permissions work". Just because "Everyone" has ACL permissions doesn't mean anyone on the network can access your information.  Specifically, they would have to get by Windows Authentication (Kerberos in your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to take ownership of the folder.

Launch a command prompt as administrator, and then run:
`takeown /F C:\Path\to\the\folder`

This should take ownership of the folder, and allow you to read and change permissions on it. From here, right-click on it in windows explorer, select `Properties`, select the `Security` tab, click `Advanced`, click `Change Permissions`, and then select the Deny permission and click `Remove`. Click `OK` until the windows are closed.

Comment: @user19185 If that happened, then I think it's time to invest in a proper backup solution ;)