# You dont currently have permission to access this folder error

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I bought a new SATA Hard drive and installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 on it. I also installed my old one beside the new SATA HD.

Now I want to access my images / musics and videos but I get this error:

> You dont currently have permission to access this folder, click continue to permanently get access to this folder

and when I click continue, I get this new error:

> You have been denied permission to access this folder

when I go to the securiy tabs, my username (which is also the administrator on the pc) is not there - My new HDD is called `C:` and the old one is `E:` - I tried [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/312867/is-there-anyway-to-remove-denied-permissions-from-a-group-for-a-folder-if-i-dont) and run the CMD - but the CMD directory is:

> C:\Windows\System32>

and my drive is `E:`.

Comment: ... ok.  So, if following the advice of "takeown /F C:\Path\to\the\folder" you would change the C to E, and change \path\to\this\folder to the actual location of your stuff.  Like, if you were talking about stuff that was in a folder located at E:\Users\Johnny and you wanted to take ownership of everything in the Johnny directory, you would type "takeown /F E:\Users\Johnny" without the quotes.

Comment: The only mess is with your drive letters and as @BonGart suggest to take ownership of the directory you will be able to access the drive.

Comment: Okay , I did the takeown and i got a success message , but when I open the file I get the same no permission message

Comment: @dave what response you got lest us know about that.

Comment: I have a file called Pictures , there are 12 folders inside of it , inside each folder there is at least 5 folders , every time I try to access theme I get "You dont currently have permission to access this folder, click continue to permanently get access to this folder"

Comment: is it possible to take ownership of folders and all its sub folders?

Comment: Take a look on this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx).

Comment: @avirk I did all steps listed in that article , still not working :(

Comment: BonGart already suggest you the way to takown whole contents of the folder. Also run the [registry script](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) and see this [article](http://www.tech-forums.net/pc/f128/how-take-ownership-files-vista-win7-155100/).

Comment: i hope the following link would help to solve your problem http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/you-dont-currently-have-permission-to-access-this/42632219-3a86-40cf-b0ae-59dc5dae9df7

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot of conversation over a very simple process. I would give you command line options, but recursive junction points can be a problem. So, the most straight forward way to do this is with native Windows tools.

These are Windows 10 instructions. I have added Windows 7 notes.

1. Open `File Explorer` and right-click the E: drive. Choose `Properties`
2. Click the `Security` tab and then click the `Advanced` button.
3. Next to where it shows the Owner click `Change`. (Windows 7: Click the `Owner` tab, click `Edit`, then click `Other users or groups`.)
4. In the Select User or Group window, type `Administrator` and click `Check Names`. If you did it correctly Administrator will be underlined. Click `OK`.
5. Check the box `Replace owner on subcontainers and objects`
6. Click `Apply`

WAIT. WAIT. WAIT. WAIT some more. When done, click `OK` and close the Advanced Security Settings for Local Disk E: window.

Now:

1. Repeat steps 1 and 2 above.
2. Under the Permission entries window, click the `Add` button.
3. Next to Principal click `Select a principal`. (Windows 7: Click `Change Permissions`, then click `Add`.)
4. In the Select User or Group window type `Everyone` and click `Check Names`. If you did it properly, Everyone will be underlined. Click `OK`.
5. In the Basic permissions area, check the box next to `Full control` and click `OK`.
6. Check the box next to `Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object`
7. Click `Apply`.

WAIT. WAIT. WAIT. Wait some more. When it's done, click `OK` to close the Advanced Security Settings for Local Disk (E:) window.

NOTE: If you receive any security warnings prompting asking you to allow changes, click Yes or Allow.

You now have full access of every file on the E: drive.

Comment: Note, I accidentally gave you Windows 10 instructions. I just revised it with notes for Windows 7.

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

#### Now I want to access my images / musics and videos

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

Assuming the drive in question is `e:`

To set any user as owner:

```
icacls "e:\" /setowner "user name" /T /C
```

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "e:\" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Source [Take Ownership of a File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html)

Answer (score 2):

The old disk was created by a user account that does not exist on the new
computer.
Therefore the disk files are owned by a user that for the new computer is
non-existent and non-accessible.

You can follow the steps below:

1. Start a Command Prompt (cmd) as an administrator
2. Take ownership of the files by entering:

   ```
   takeown /f E:\ /r
   ```
3. Give yourself full rights :

   ```
   cacls E:\ /T /G username:F
   ```

The above commands have their origin in earlier versions of Windows.
The more modern utility is `icacls`. Below are some examples:

```
icacls /?
icacls folder/file /setowner username /t /c /q
icacls folder/file /grant username:F /t
```

The switches that were used for the last example:

```
username:F = Full Control to user
/t = Apply recursively to existing files and sub-folders
```

One more option of interest if the folder contains junctions:

```
/l = Performs the operation on a symbolic link versus its destination.
```

References:

- [Takeown command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.11).aspx)
- [CACLS command](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html)
- [icacls command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: I've had trouble with these commands because of NTFS junction points inside the user folders. Usually an error will be generated and the command will stop.

Comment: @Appleoddity: An alternate utility is [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which can replace both the above commands and is aware of junction points. See its parameters `/setowner` and `/l` : "Performs the operation on a symbolic link versus its destination".

Comment: You might want to edit your answer demonstrating the use of icacls as an alternative to the GUI approach. As it is now, this answer probably won't work with those two commands.

Comment: @Appleoddity: Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Variation of problem I experienced:

I had windows 7 installed but it was giving me issues so i re installed the same windows (windows 7 ultimate) on top of the old and suddenly a whole drive was not allowing me access and when i was hit with all the prompts i was going through the security tabs to find out what was going on, it was coming up saying the owner of the file is unknown, i would then set my admin as owner and then i was able to get into the file but the movie inside was coming up saying it was again incorrect user.

Fix used:

First of all I right click on the hard drive itself then:

1. properties
2. Security
3. in group or username I selected edit (if you already have a Everyone user skip to .6)
4. add
5. in enter the object name Type: Everyone then press check names then OK
6. highlight the everyone user and tick the allow all box then apply
7. reselect the user Everyone and select advanced
8. select owner tab at top
   if yours is like mine it will say something like current owner is unknown (not a direct quote)
9. select edit at the bottom
10. select admin then select the tick box Replace Owner on sub containers and objects (very important you tick) select apply.

This will then go through all the files and sub files and change owner to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself admin
Open Elevated CMD window and fix your username not being in Admin group

```
net localgroup administrators YOURUSERNAME /add
```

Then 
Change drive letter (E:) to your drive letter and run the below

```
TAKEOWN /F E:\ /R /D Y
```

Or my favorite

```
ICACLS "E:\*" /reset /T
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the existing answers before hopping in.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answer is perfect, but the easiest method is to use 3rd party program called [**"take ownership"**](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/system_tools/misc_system_tools/take_ownership_shell_extension.cfm).

Just install and on the desired folder right click and select **Take ownership**

[image: Take ownership]