# How to enable permission to access USER folder on external hdd (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

My computer crashed but the HDD is intact. I have been able to browse that hard drive from another Windows computer, except for the Users folder where I get the message:

> "You dont currently have permission to access this folder" [continue] [cancel].

Also, I do *not* get *access denied* msg.

When I click continue it just hangs.

Comment: Nope. I do not get "access denied" message.

Comment: While the accepted answers are more complicated, this answer is still completely valid and is very likely to be exactly what you need: https://superuser.com/a/1233270/74026 The point is that you need to take ownership of the files. The dialog is probably not hanging, it is just taking a while to process what it needs to process. Using the methods at the linked answer will give you an indicator of the process the system goes through to gain access to the folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems was that the folder was large and it took long time to process.